# Update record, involves Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

I have a form to edit a record. The form is identical to the create new record. (Except for the wording). When I click submit it gives, nilLNilClass. My code works for my updating my other records that don't involve a Join Table so I am not sure what is wrong.

The Form:

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :type %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :type %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category %><br>
<%= f.select :category, [ ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Surveillance", "ip_video_surveillance"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"] ], {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg", :id => "category" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>

<div id="container" style="width:1140px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<button type="button" class="reset">Reset Search</button>
<table width="100%" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th width="5%" class="filter-false"><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
  <th width="37%" data-placeholder="Search">Content</th>
  <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">Type</th>
  <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">Category</th>
  <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">Product</th>
  <th width="10%" data-placeholder="Search">User</th>
  <th width="8%" data-placeholder="Search">Active</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @questions.each do |q| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "test[question_ids][]", q.id, @test.question_ids.include?(q.id) %></td>
    <td><%= q.content %></td>
    <td><%= q.question_type %></td>
    <td><%= q.category %></td>
    <td>GXP</td>
    <td><%= q.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= q.active %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Update Test", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
before_action :set_test, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]  
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :show, :update, :destroy]

def edit
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])
  @questions = Question.all
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @test.update(test_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def test_params
    params.require(:test).permit(:name, :user_id, :type, :category, :description, :question_ids => [], questions_attributes: [ :id ] ).
    merge user_id: current_user.id
end
```

Error:

```
Started PATCH "/tests/98" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-20 10:12:58 -0400
Processing by TestsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x=", "test"=>{"name"=>"one two three four, spelling YEah!!", "type"=>"", "category"=>"ip_voice", "description"=>"not so smart, wooops", "question_ids"=>["1"]}, "commit"=>"Update Test", "id"=>"98"}
Test Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tests".* FROM "tests" WHERE "tests"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "98"]]
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'x' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:56:in `block in update'
app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:55:in `update'
```

This is line 56: `if @test.update(test_params)`

I did think it was wierd that I had to define @test in edit(). I also tried @test.save with same error. I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Do you have a `before_action` for setting `@test` variable in your controller? if not you have to define one

Comment: Wait, I do, before_action :set_test, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] Isn't that what you mean?

Comment: And you have to define the action too for that.Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `@test` in `update` action. Currently its not defined so its value is `nil` and you receive the error.

Add this line in `update` action, before calling `@test.update`:

```
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
```

I see that you have a `before_action` callback for setting test i.e., `set_test`. In that case, you don't need

```
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
```

in `update` action. All you need to do is add `update` action in `before_action` callback as:

```
before_action :set_test, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Also, I would suggest you to **remove** the `@test` setting from `edit` action as you have already added `edit` action in `before_action` callback

Finally, `set_test` (ideally `private` method) method should look like:

```
def set_test
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Is this only needed for Join Table records? My other controller don't define anything in edit()?

Comment: Its not related to join table records. Its a basic Ruby thing, you have to set the variable(be it instance variable or local variable, in your case instance variable) value before using it.

Comment: Pavan mentioned using before filters. I added to my question. Should those work?

Comment: Yes, if you have `before_action` for setting test, you just need to add the `action` name there.

Comment: As i said before,you are a big competitor! Good to see your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this in your controller

`before_action :set_test, only: [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]` and at the end of your controller

```
private

def set_test

@test = Test.find(params[:id])

end
```

And also,update your edit method like this

```
def edit
  #@test = Test.find(params[:id]) remove this line you wont need it.
  @questions = Question.all
end
```

**OR**

You can just follow **@kirti Thorat**'s answer.

Comment: Oh, okay. Great, two answers to a problem. :D +1

Comment: Pavan, you have a typo `[:show,:edit,:update.:destroy]` make it `:update, :destroy` (**Note** comma and not dot)

Comment: Might as well correct my name in your answer, its Kirti and not Kriti :D

Comment: @KirtiThorat My bad! Corrected :D